# How do I know a particular button was clicked inside a List

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have this list, populated from Core Data:

```
    List {
      ForEach(items.filter {
        self.searchText.isEmpty ? true : $0.term!.contains(self.searchText)
      }, id: \.self) { item in
        
        Button(action: {
          selectedItem = items.firstIndex { $0 == item }!
          changeDescription()
          print(selectedItem)
          
        }) {
          
          Text(item.term!)
            .font(fontItems)
            .disabled(true)
            .foregroundColor(items[selectedItem] == item ? .black : .white)
        }
```

the last line,

```
.foregroundColor(items[selectedItem] == item ? .black : .white)
```

is my try to detect if that button was clicked. In that case, I want to change the font color to black.

The app crashes on that line when I try to scroll the list, with the message:

```
__boundsFail: index 18446744073709551615 beyond bounds [0 .. 605]'
```

I am new to SwiftUI.

How do I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of storing index (which differs in full and filtered arrays) store `item` directly (just make its type Equatable), ie

```
Button(action: {
  selectedItem = item       // << store item in selection
  changeDescription()
  print(selectedItem)
  
}) {
  
  Text(item.term!)
    .font(fontItems)
    .disabled(true)
    .foregroundColor(selectedItem == item ? .black : .white) // compare item
}
```

Comment: Brilliant! Much easier like that. I cannot upvote you enough!!!!!!!!!!!!!